# Space engineers monospace font workaround

Tags: space-engineers

I'm currently writing some ingame scripts in space engineers (vanilla) to show certain data on ingame LCD panels. Besides text I also want to display some diagrams. Unfortunately space engineers LCD panels do not provide monospaced font what makes it quite difficult to generate ASCII art diagrams.

The only way to get what I want is try to find characters that have the same width which is the case for `|` and `'` or for `_` and `x`.

Can anyone provide a list of such equal-width characters? I still did not find any set of 3 chars with same length.

Edit for clarification: I'm not searching for a *technical* workaround (like replacing the font of the game).

[image: A graph on an ingame lcd panel]

Comment: This would make for an extremely helpful script. Looks great!

Comment: Maybe you can find something in this ASCII Table? http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Unforntunately this does not help very much as the character width is unique for this font. In addition to that the most special characters (like █ ) do not work in SE.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.reddit.com/r/spaceengineers/comments/3mgk8w/any_way_to_get_monospaced_fonts/cvg7b48

Comment: This is just a local solution and not even a mod. It won't work for multiplayer for example.

Comment: As I postet below in my answer you can get all available characters via FontData.xml. No monospaced character variants listet there, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that the font data are stored in `FontData.xml` (`SpaceEngineers\Content\Fonts\..`). There are also the font widths listed so it is quite easy to find those with same size.

Promising groups are (only special characters listed):

Size 25: `,-.:;[]{}·`

Size 22:  `|'´¦ˉ`

It's not much but more than I knew before. Unfortunately the space `' '` has size 15 so you cannot replace one of those characters with a space (not even with multiple spaces).

Comment: I suppose it all depends on how you feel about multi-character "blocks".  In 75 pixels you can either fit 5 spaces or 3 characters from the Size 25 group.  Not widely applicable, but this idea could be used for indented sections of your display.